# Testing IOS Safari Anchor links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ios

I found that Safari on a mobile device like an iPhone or iPad doesn't play with anchor links.
It just doesn't take the `#link` with it.

After reading a lot of online 'solutions' for this I didn't found anything usefull. So I want to try the following but I'm a little bit struggeling with the coding.

Here is the idea.
I want to `$_POST` the `#link` in the url. In the hope that it stays in the url.

The problem is that I'm using a `<a href="#">` link to do this.
Is is possible to do a `$_POST` in a `a href` link?

Here are the basics:

```
$link_a = '#A';    
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/scroll<?php $_POST['$link_a']?>" title="A">A</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what is really needed but there is a thing I noticed:

Shouldn't your `<?php $_POST['$list_a'] ?>` be `<?php $_POST[$list_a] ?>` ?

Because, it seems to me that you are querying for a value in array $_POST with key == '$list_a' but I am guessing you want to query by '#A' isn't it ?

Comment: Thnx. The problem I have now is that the `#A` isn't added so I first need to figure out how to add the link via `$_POST`

Comment: I found that it isn't possible to add a `$_POST` in a `href` so I need another solution. Unicode doesn't work either!

Comment: you might be missing an echo. Try this:  `<?php echo $_POST[$list_a] ?>`. The complete thing should possibly look like: `<a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url')?>/scroll<?php echo $_POST[$link_a]?>" title="A">A</a>`.